# App rejected for REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, (removed the casuing package but still)

Tags: android, flutter

What to do in this Situation?
Already removed the package (open_file) which was casing the problem, but still rejected!
What i have to do anything else in Privacy policy section?
#flutter

[image]

Issue found: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose.

We found that your app is not compliant with how REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.

Comment: open_file was casing the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem, the main problem was i used a app bundle in open testing track which was casing the rejection. If you are facing this problem simply follow my steps:

1. Check if there is any sensitive permission's in your app's manifest(merged) file in build folder.
2. Check in google play console's App Content section where you will find your affected appbundle and verison No. Just go through every policy you submitted.
3. Check open testing, internal testing and other tracks if those have any affected build
4. Create a release to the affected track (mine was open testing)
5. If still got rejected , you can appeal to google from google play console. They will provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

**Upload a new, compliant APK/app bundle and make sure the new release is rolled out 100% to completely deactivate the non-compliant APK.**

Answer (score 0):

you can try those steps

- Go to **android/app/src/**  the delete **debug** folder
- check manifest file at **android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**
  remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from there
- increase app version build and release it again

Comment: aready removed it, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is some steps you can follow->

1. Remove your old build files on both build and android/app/build
2. Clear previous pub cache and re run flutter pub get
   Then rebuild your app. After that check your merged menifest on build folder to confirm if the permission is still there or not. If not submit again. If any previous submit already contains this permission please pause that track ( any track open/closed/internal test)